# SQL: I need to select where 3 rows are the same on consecutive dates

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with a PersonID, ItemID, Quantity, and DateBought as the columns. I need to select rows where PersonID, ItemID, and Quantity are the same and DateBought is on consecutive days.

Here is some sample data

```
PersonID    ItemID    Quantity    DateBought
1           A         1           2015-02-01
1           A         1           2015-02-02
2           B         2           2015-02-01
2           B         1           2015-02-02
3           C         2           2015-02-01
3           C         2           2015-02-01
4           D         1           2015-02-01
4           E         1           2015-02-02
5           G         7           2015-09-21
5           G         7           2015-09-22
```

In this situation, i'd want to select PersonID = 1 and PersonID = 5, and no others (2 has diff quantities, 3 is on the same day, 4 different items.)

Comment: MySQL and/or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: Is it SQL Server or MySQL? What version? Or you need solution for both?  Solution for SQL Server 2012+ would be likely much more efficient. What result do you want to see if `Person` has three or more rows with consecutive days?

Comment: MySQL Or MS SqL Server??

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` :-

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY PersonID, ItemID, Quantity ORDER BY DateBought DEsc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY PersonID, ItemID, Quantity ORDER BY DateBought ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2 
on t1.personID = t2.personID and t1.ItemID = t2.ItemID and t1.Quantity= t2.Quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT DateBought d,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateBought) i
  FROM @d
  GROUP BY DateBought
)
SELECT MIN(d),MAX(d)
FROM t
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,i,d)
```

By using this u will get min_date and max_date from DateBought column after u just need to fethch the other values as you want from table by using simple condition.

Answer (score 0):

The Tabibitosan method (see https://community.oracle.com/message/3996302) should do the trick... Assuming Your data is stored in a temp-table like "#temp" the SQL would be:

```
Select  a.*
from    (   
Select  PersonID    
, ItemID    
, Quantity  
, MIN(DateBought) as minDat
, MAX(DateBought) as maxDat     
from    (
Select  PersonID    
, ItemID    
, Quantity
, DateBought    
, DATEDIFF(day,STR(YEAR(DateBought),4)+'0101',DateBought)+1 - ROW_NUMBER() over(order by PersonID, DateBought) as distance  
from    #temp
) as a

group by    distance
, PersonID  
, ItemID    
, Quantity  
) as a
where   abs(DATEDIFF(dd, minDat, maxDat)) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select a.* from sample a,sample b where a.personid=b.personid and a.itemid=b.itemid and a.datebought=(b.datebought)-1
union select b.* from sample a,sample b where a.personid=b.personid and a.itemid=b.itemid and b.datebought=(a.datebought)+1;
```

output :

```
PersonID    ItemID    Quantity    DateBought
1           A         1           2015-02-01
1           A         1           2015-02-02
5           G         7           2015-09-21
5           G         7           2015-09-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. abs may not be needed on [DateDiff].

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Test') is not null
    drop table #Test;
select *
into #Test
from (
          select 1 as PersonId, 'A' as ItemId, 1 as Quantity, cast('2015-02-01' as date) as DateBought
union all select 1 as PersonId, 'A' as ItemId, 1 as Quantity, cast('2015-02-02' as date) as DateBought
union all select 2 as PersonId, 'B' as ItemId, 2 as Quantity, cast('2015-02-01' as date) as DateBought
union all select 2 as PersonId, 'B' as ItemId, 1 as Quantity, cast('2015-02-02' as date) as DateBought
union all select 3 as PersonId, 'C' as ItemId, 2 as Quantity, cast('2015-02-01' as date) as DateBought
union all select 3 as PersonId, 'C' as ItemId, 2 as Quantity, cast('2015-02-01' as date) as DateBought
union all select 4 as PersonId, 'D' as ItemId, 1 as Quantity, cast('2015-02-01' as date) as DateBought
union all select 4 as PersonId, 'E' as ItemId, 1 as Quantity, cast('2015-02-02' as date) as DateBought
union all select 5 as PersonId, 'G' as ItemId, 7 as Quantity, cast('2015-09-21' as date) as DateBought
union all select 5 as PersonId, 'G' as ItemId, 7 as Quantity, cast('2015-09-22' as date) as DateBought)a


select PersonId
, ItemId
, Quantity
, DateBought 
from (
        select 
            PersonId
            , ItemId
            , Quantity
            , DateBought
            ,  abs(datediff(DAY, lead(DateBought) over (Partition by PersonId, ItemId, Quantity order by DateBought desc), DateBought)) as [DateDiff]
        from #Test
    ) Results
where Results.[DateDiff]= 1
```